# New tab that hold no records and goes straight to page

Tags: lightning

When I click on the chasing tab on the navigation menu, I want to be redirected to a global custom page.

When I click chasing now, I get the displayed page.
[image]

I want to redirect to this page directly.
[image]

Question) How can I directly navigate to a custom page, when I click on the custom tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gqgBAAQ), go to **Setup -> Object Manager -> Chasing (custom object) -> Buttons, Links and Actions**.  Click the Edit action on the *Chasing Tab* and then set the tab override settings as you see fit.  All options can be seen [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_customize_override.htm&type=5)